# "It was daylight" vs. "there was daylight"

Tags: phrase-choice

Daylight refers to the light that's produced by the sun during the day. So "there" should be used to refer to it. Like in "there was light."

Still, *it was daylight* [seems to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20was%20daylight%2C%20there%20was%20daylight&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20daylight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20daylight%3B%2Cc0) more common than *there was daylight.*

Why could be the reason?

Comment: Why do you think that "there" must always be used to refer to daylight? "It was daylight" is a common statement in stories to identify what time of day it is. This logical assumption could be easily corrected by reading more English texts.

Comment: [correction: What could be the reason? or Why is this so?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used for times of day, for weather, for events on a calendar, and for events at specific times of day: "It was 2 o'clock", "It was raining", "It was Easter", "It was lunchtime", "It was dawn", "It was going home time". Saying "It was daylight" is saying what time it was.

You can also use "it was" to in other ways, such as to identify things that have already been mentioned: "What was the light?" "It was daylight." But I don't think that's relevant.